# A question on how heat treatment is done in bogies

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, metallurgy, metals, heat-treatment

During heat treatment of metals I find that Normalizing is done in railway bogies and tempering is done following normalizing only for the CP top and bottom. Following the tempering process quenching takes place for manganese steel. I am basically very new to the wagon industry. Hence a slightly detailed explanation about the same is very much sought out for. It would be great if someone gives me a detailed insight into these from an industry perspective.

Comment: https://www.kloecknermetals.com/blog/the-three-stages-of-heat-treatment/

Comment: "Normalize and temper " is only done on conventional steels , not "metals". I don't think you are going to become a metallurgist with a few paragraphs on Stack  Exchange .